# setting serverside file as value for input file type with a click on button or link (javascript and/or php?)

Tags: php, javascript, file, types

I have a upload field where people can upload a image. I'd like to add a link next to it that says: **use default**

So when the user doesn't have a image to upload they can click on the link that will set a specific file (on the webserver) for that field. For example: **default_picture1.jpg**

I've read that it's not possible (for security reasons) to use javascript to set the value of a input file type. I understand the clientside security reasons but what I'm trying to achieve is setting the value with a file on the **webserver** which is already there that can be used when the guest doesn't have a picture to upload.

I tried with js but obviously doesn't work:

```
<label>Picture 1</label>
<input title="" size="60" id="pic1" name="pic1" type="file" />

<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('pic1').value = 'test1.jpeg';">test1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('pic1').value = 'test2.jpeg';">test2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="document.forms['form_upload'].elements['pic1'].value = 'test3.jpeg';">test3</a>
```

(btw: I was just trying 3 different ways of setting the value in JS)

Maybe it's possible to do it with php?

If you have another idea that has to do with this, please feel free to post.

I highly appreciate your help and taking time to answer!

Regards,

Gosa

Comment: Why not just have a default image that gets used if the user doesn't upload one?  The user shouldn't have to click a button to use the default.

Comment: Hi, it's not my call. They want to show clearly that they can choose a default picture but thanks for replying, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not set due to the security. Imagine if you could set the file to some cookie file in user's computer or any other personal information rich data.

I would simply have a button to click if user wants a default image which would contain an image near the button. You can retrieve the image if user click the button. It's your imagination.

Comment: Hi, I added a radio button where they have to click if they want to use the image that is proposed(default image).
Thanks for the response by the way. I was so busy that I forgot to thank you for your time

Comment: @Gosa, glad that helped a bit! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a hidden field to your form. Then, when you click one of the server side images you would set the value on the hidden field instead.

Then on the server you check the contents of that variable if a file has not been uploaded.

Comment: I did something similar to what you suggested. Thanks!